# What is the way to delete data from a particular column of a table in Oracle 10g using SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

Example:

Table_A

```
id    | not null | number(10) 
name  | not null | varchar(50)  
photo | not null | blob
```

If I want to delete blob data of column `photo` from Table `A`

My table consists around 2,000,000 rows, hence it becomes time consuming to execute `UPDATE` statement.

My approach:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY EXT_DIR as '/tmp/TEST/';

CREATE TABLE TABLE_TEMP
(   
    ID varchar2(10),
    NAME varchar2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
(
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY EXT_DIR
    ACCESS PARAMETERS 
    (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
        (
            ID char(10),
            NAME char(50)
        )
    )
    LOCATION ('TABLE_A.csv') ---dump taken from TABLE_A
)
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
/

INSERT INTO TABLE_A(ID,NAME) SELECT ID,NAME FROM TABLE_TEMP;
```

My approach was taking table data into CSV and using EXTERNAL TABLE to insert CSV data into my table but as CSV can store upto 1048576 rows only, hence looking for different ways.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not for how-to questions, so you should do some search, try something and then, if you still need help, post a question

Comment: Ok noted! First of all, my table consists around 20 lac rows, hence it becomes time consuming to execute `UPDATE` statement. My approach was taking table data into CSV and using EXTERNAL TABLE to insert CSV data into my table but as CSV can store upto 1048576 rows.

Comment: If you can do DDL statements, drop the column and then add it again. But what about the NOT NULL constraint on the column?

Comment: I can remove NOT NULL from that column but using DDL changes my table structure.

Comment: Do you have triggers on the table you need to preserve, etc.? In principle, it would be easiest to create an empty table with the same structure (column names and data types) as the existing one; `create table table_temp as select * from table_a where 0 = 1` is a common way to do it. Then `insert into table_temp select id, name, NULL from table_a`. Then drop `table_a` and rename `table_temp` to `table_a`. You would have to recreate indexes and triggers etc., but that should be quick and easy.

Answer (score 2):

First off all to peoples who answered like `delete col from table`, there is no such statement in oracle to delete column values , `delete` statement removes rows. Please before answer be sure that it's corresponds to question.

You should update table
`update table_a set photo = null`, 
But looking to your table description you can not do that due to column defined `not null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete some rows of the photo column then you have to previously alter that table

```
ALTER TABLE TableA modify (photo NULL);
```

Then you can "erase" some data setting it to null:

```
UPDATE TableA SET photo = null
```

If you want to drop the column then

```
ALTER TABLE TableA DROP photo;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE photo FROM [Table A]
```

Try this out

Comment: sorry..it works for sql server dbms .  
If the columns are nullable you could just run a query to null them:

`UPDATE [Table A] set photo=NULL`

Comment: if you want to still delete it, first change the column to nullable ie `ALTER TABLE [TABLE A] modify (photo NULL);` then run  `UPDATE [Table A] set photo=NULL` then set it back to not nullable `ALTER TABLE [TABLE A] modify (photo NOT NULL);`